# TypeScript error when calling function with union-typed parameter

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript, I have defined `WeightedItem` and `createWeightedTable` as follows:

```
type WeightedItem<T> = { item: T; weight: number };

const createWeightedTable = <T>(items: WeightedItem<T>[] | T[], options?: Options): WeightedTable<T>
```

I was surprised to find out that this:

```
const weightedItems = [{ item: "a" }];

createWeightedTable(weightedItems)
```

Makes TypeScript complain about the following:

```
Argument of type '{ item: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WeightedItem<string>[] | string[]'.
  Type '{ item: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'WeightedItem<string>[]'.
    Property 'weight' is missing in type '{ item: string; }' but required in type 'WeightedItem<string>'.ts(2345)
```

However, these variations do not:

```
const weightedItems = [{ item: "a", foo: "bar" }];

createWeightedTable(weightedItems);
```

```
const weightedItems = [{ weigtht: 1 }];

createWeightedTable(weightedItems);
```

Why is that?

Why does TypeScript assume that `{ item: "a" }` is a "defective" `WeightedItem` instead of just another generic `T`, but the same is not true for `{ item: "a", foo: "bar" }` or `{ weight: 1 }`?

**EDIT:**

Added minimal reproducible example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6hCWBzAFsCATAkmgtgHgBUA+KAXigG8p5cAuKAgbigHcEVh6A7AVxwCMIAJygBfRgFgAUNIDGAey4BnYFFlCIAQzRwkqDAU38ANtHKEANEQAUNCDiX1dHDNnuEiAbQC6UAD4MPgCUZCQUotJyiiqs7PpYuEoAjGRQnlR2OPQARJrZYt6SMlLqWjpxaOiGJhDWbHqVbg5JQUVRyqr1Lgn2SgBMqenUdFC52RZQAGby8jn8mkL5ooWRJRraEM7x1aZ1Fa6Jfa2rCh2xDQe9AMyDVF2o9CnLbWtlm-tVRrv3jYlXrUA) as suggested.

Comment: ① Could you make this a [mre] by reducing to [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMzLZW) instead of including undeclared things?

Comment: ② Looks like the same phenomenon as reported in [ms/TS#29471](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29471), which is classified as a bug.  TypeScript's inference algorithm collects candidates based on some kind of "priority", and it looks like it chose unwisely here from `WeightedItem<T>[]` instead of from `T[]`, possibly based on the union order (which I guess is a bug?)  You could "fix" it by swapping the order as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w6pqYm) but then you'd never get the other inference.  Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: ③ The [mre] should be in the question as plaintext.  I wasn't suggesting you include a playground link (although that's a nice supplement); I was asking you to remove the distracting undeclared stuff from the question.  Could you please [edit] to do that?  Or I'll do it if you want.

Comment: Sorry @jcalz, I'm not sure what you mean by undeclared stuff. But go ahead and edit the question as you see fit. And to address your previous comment, yes, that seems to be exactly what's going on. It does fully address the question, thank you.

Comment: I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance (on mobile at the moment, might be ~5hrs from now)

Comment: Alright. Meanwhile, I have edited the question in an attempt to minimize fluff. Let me know if this is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is considered a bug in TypeScript, as reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#29471](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29471), although it's been open a very long time and there's no indication it will be addressed anytime soon.

TypeScript's inference algorithm uses various heuristics, such as assigning "priority" levels to [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *inference sites*, places from which inferences can be made, and then using the highest priority site to come up with a candidate for inference.  If that candidate doesn't work, the compiler generally just reports an error instead of falling back to a lower priority inference site.  The inference algorithm is by no means perfect, and is not a formally correct *full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))* algorithm as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), but it behaves well in a wide variety of real world code, and so changing it to fix your problem might well do more harm than good.  By this I mean to say: it's probably best to assume this isn't going to change.

Anyway, in `WeightedItem<T>[] | T[]` there are two inference sites for the type parameter `T`, like `WeightedItem<T₁>[] | T₂[]`.  It seems that the compiler is assigning `T₁` a higher priority than `T₂`, and everything follows from that.  You can apparently change this behavior by swapping the order of the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members, like `T[] | WeightedItem<T>[]`:

```
type WeightedItem<T> = { item: T; weight: number };
declare const createWeightedTable: <T>(
    items: T[] | WeightedItem<T>[]) => WeightedTable<T>;

const weightedItems = [{ item: "a" }];
const r1 = createWeightedTable(weightedItems);
// const ret: WeightedTable<{ item: string; }>
```

Unfortunately though, this will prevent the second union member from ever being matched, since any array will match `T[]`, including those that match `WeightedItem<T>[]`:

```
const w: WeightedItem<string> = { item: "b", weight: 123 }
const r2 = createWeightedTable([w])
// const r2: WeightedTable<WeightedItem<string>>
```

If you want to work around it, you might have to guide the types more explicitly, perhaps with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type UnwrapWeightedItem<T> = T extends WeightedItem<infer U> ? U : T
declare const createWeightedTable: <T>(
    items: T[]) => WeightedTable<UnwrapWeightedItem<T>>;

const weightedItems = [{ item: "a" }];
const r1 = createWeightedTable(weightedItems);
// const ret: WeightedTable<{ item: string; }> 

const w: WeightedItem<string> = { item: "b", weight: 123 }
const r2 = createWeightedTable([w])
// const r2: WeightedTable<string>
```

That works because we just let `T` be inferred as the array element type, and then compute the type argument for `WeightedTable<>` from it with the conditional type `UnwrapWeightedItem<T>`.  It's not ideal, especially inside your function implementation where generic conditional types are harder for the compiler to understand, but at least you can compute the types from the caller's side.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6hCWBzAFsCATAkmgtgHgBUA+KAXigG8p5cAuKAgbigHcEVh6A7AVxwCMIAJygBfRgFgAUKEix2qDAQCG-ADYRCJclQAe++gTHTpXZTggBnMMoDG0AIKVpUV1HQRba5UOi2A9lyWwFC2vspocEiK6CrqEPRaABQubmk0EDiWhgDaALpQAD7y0WhYuFr5AJRkJFEcSqoaWiZSaQFBIWylGNiZlmRQOVQZOPQARMrjYnmSbW4dwVBCAIyDYRAREPUxcRpJ3Q3l-VVzaQD056GBS76cJUd7miN0UMFC8FyIzKIkgLwbgFkd1rtG5deg7Mp9fDvT6IbSUaivcb8cYAGlYCnuKwATABmYzzVyLEJCbHrcKRTGNeJJHIsPJVVKuS7XTrLbHgqmxJqaCG9Cowr5Ef6AOR3WqJWmYLNY7NAAELOKRMqCyaAAVS4LCEyjAfOO+GIgyMEF0aC46AGeqheE+ADNhFA1SQAPyOqCGZUeLw+Pyg0IU7Zcp6JYgpQlpRH9XIM2oPXY8vAarU6q0VYhEObK4kYnr6gbkYaRsZQSbTUSzLN+1bkzaU3NPA5cqGWU7KlnZu6c+sJl6ZeiC75if5ApXh7MsLtHa0D+G94vItE5jj0HH4iVjqtk8gbLZ6ht0hltq4djlxspPPAzqCA8VAA)

Comment: While switching the order of the types does make the problem go away, how come `{ weight: 1}` doesn't throw an error? It should still partially match `WeightedItem,<T>` just as `{ item: "a" }` does. Is that also related to inference site priority somehow?

Comment: I'm sure it's related to site priority, but it's almost certainly also related to other things as well.  Clearly the matching algorithm does something differently in the different cases, so it's more complicated than *just* inference site priority.