# TypeScript predicates not working with generics?

Tags: typescript

Take a look at the following snippet:

```
type WeightedItem<T> = { item: T; weight: number };

const isWeightedItemArray = <T>(items: WeightedItem<T>[] | T[]): items is WeightedItem<T>[] => {
  return (items as WeightedItem<T>[]).every((item: WeightedItem<T>) => "weight" in item);
};

export const createWeightedTable = <T>(items: T[]) => {
  if (isWeightedItemArray(items)) {
    // items is typed as  T[] & WeightedItem<T>[], and weight does not exist on type T
    const weights = (items).map((item) => item.weight);
  }
}
```

I created `isWeightedItemArray` to guarantee that `items` is of type `WeightedItem<T>[]`, and yet TypeScript still throws an error and would apparently force me to type cast `items` to `WeightedItem<T>[]` even after using the [predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) function.

Why is `items` typed as `T[] & WeightedItem<T>[]` and not just `WeightedItem<T>[]` after the predicate function?

Minimal reproducible example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6hCWBzAFsCATAkmgtgHgBUA+KAXigG8p5cAuKAgbigHcEVh6A7AVxwCMIAJygBfRgFgAUNIDGAey4BnYNSVwkqDNgg4AgkKEBDEGSiEiAChq6l9DR224LAbQC6UAD4N3ASno2OEpqsOxaWM7E7mQkFNJQUEIQwDxCXFDWuMFGwQ7hOvhRbr4AdBAAbsIglpm69mFoEboWvjFQAERsmsDt1OmBvpJS4tLSEAAeYPJCqgrKs0lGaHmNBEb8ADbQ5Ba1QfQEfm1xUgnwAGYZ8OoNTroGxtWBSr6tJwkJAPSf1FkhoJB0FAcglDh4AGShbp3QpEdwAGmBXCBXQ4UHQ8ggwS48lUE2uqkUUAB0AI8Q+cxUrAawXIexeJRwRjANQGbUCJVRqEG5NE0lEQA).

Comment: Did you mean to use `type WeightedItem<T> = T & { weight: number };` instead? You haven't checked that the items have an `"item"` property.

Comment: You're right, I should probably check for the `"item"` property as well for consistency's sake. In the end, `item` is what I intend to return from the weighted table, so it should probably also exist. I am open to suggestions regarding other possible type configurations though.

Comment: Well, I think something is suspicious about your type definitions because you're saying that a `T[]` array is actually (_also_) an `{ item: T }[]` array.

Comment: My intention was to either accept an array of whatever in which elements already contain their own `weight` property (in the shape of  `{ item: whatever; weight: number }`), or an array of pure whatever which would then be converted to `{ item: whatever; weight: number }`, either with default weights or potentially with weights coming from a second argument. Are these incompatible?

Comment: Where are you doing the conversion from pure whatever to `{ item: whatever; weight: number }`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want your `T` and `WeightedItem<T>` to be separate objects, where `{item: T, weight: number}` has the item as a property. If that understanding is correct, then the problem is that you have declared `items: T[]` when logically you want it to be either `T[]` or `WeightedItem<T>[]`. If it can't be the latter then it wouldn't make sense to test it with your `isWeightedItemArray` function!

So the solution is simply to correct the parameter's type:

```
export const createWeightedTable = <T>(items: T[] | WeightedItem<T>[]): void => {
  // ...
}
```

Then the `isWeightedItemArray` type predicate can correctly narrow the type of `items` to that branch of the union.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA6hCWBzAFsCATAkmgtgHgBUA+KAXigG8p5cAuKAgbigHcEVh6A7AVxwCMIAJygBfRgFgAUNIDGAey4BnYNSVwkqDNgg4AgkKEBDEGSiEiAChq6l9DR224LAbQC6UAD4N3ASno2OEpqsOxaWM7E7mQkFNJQUEIQwDxCXFDWuMFGwQ7hOvhRbr4AdBAAbsIglpm69mFoEboWvjFQAERsmsDt1OmBvpJS4tLSEAAeYPJCqgrKs0lGaHmNBEb8ADbQ5Ba1QfQE0d4rTs1F-lDl8vDobXFSCfAAZhnw6g2n+oYme0q+rfcEgkAPTA6hZEKgSC3HIJQ4eABkoW6n1cbgANFAjFxbl0OFB0PIIMEuPJVBM3qpFFAodACPEgXMVKwGsFyL9SjgjGAagM2oESnjUIMGaJpKIgA)

Comment: You are correct, that does fix *this* issue, but unfortunately it seems to create another: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76020085/2887078. I guess I'm stuck.

Comment: @Tiago It seems to me that that problem is a different one and either way, this is the correct type annotation. The root cause of that problem is that your two options, `T[]` and `WeightedItem<T>[]` are not distinguishable to the type inference algorithm because `WeightedItem` could be `T` - and indeed, testing for the existence of the `weight` and `item` properties doesn't logically entail that the object really is a `WeightedItem<T>` rather than a `T`. So really what you need is a proper discriminant that would allow you to distinguish these cases. Either way, giving `items` the wrong ...

Comment: ... parameter type isn't the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it like this - with no generics, as none of those functions actually need the T type that you declare, so you can use `unknown` there:

```
type WeightedItem<T> = { item: T; weight: number };

const isWeightedItemArray = (items: WeightedItem<unknown>[] | unknown[]): items is WeightedItem<unknown>[] => {
  return items.every(item => item && typeof item === 'object' && 'weight' in item);
};

export const createWeightedTable = (items: unknown[] | WeightedItem<unknown>[]): void => {
  if (isWeightedItemArray(items)) {
    const weights = (items).map((item) => item.weight);
  }
}
```

Note: The createWeightedTable needs rewriting anyway, because the question author added some new requirements in the comments.

**Update:** And a version with `<T>` type (thanks to **kaya3**)

```
const isWeightedItemArray = <T>(items: WeightedItem<T>[] | unknown[]): items is WeightedItem<T>[] => {
  return items.every(item => item && typeof item === 'object' && 'weight' in item);
};
```

Here it is more explicit that we verify if that is `WeightedItem<T>[]`.

For simplicity, you could declare types like:

```
type WeightedArray = WeightedItem<unknown>[];
```

Comment: I would like the return type of `createWeightedTable` to eventually be defined though. Or rather: I would like one of its methods to be able to return `T` as defined in `{ item: T; weight: number }`.

Comment: You didn't include that in your question so I answered to what was asked, i.e. to make the provided code work. If you want to return something specific from your function, then change the `void` return type to whatever you want to return, then build it and return. Now, the question was to fix your isWeightedItemArray function, which I did. I hope it helps.

Comment: @rsp The question clearly says that the purpose of `isWeighteditemArray` is *"to guarantee that `items` is of type `WeightedItem<T>[]`"*.

Comment: @rsp I created a minimal snippet for my question with the intention of reproducing the issue as cleanly as possible. I can eliminate `createWeightedTable`'s return type if it's causing confusion. I guess the more concise question would be: why is items still typed as `T[] & WeightedItem<T>[]` even after the predicate function?

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, but the `T` type is not constrained in any way in the isWeightedItemArray function - there is no `<T extends ...>` so T is really `any` here. It is visible when you add `<T>` there and change all `unknown` to `T` - you'll see one of the TS errors being "Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type." and there are other type errors. But now I tweaked a little bit and made it work with T - so thanks for thee idea :) I'll update the answer and give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: @Tiago, "why is items still typed as T[] & WeightedItem<T>[] even after the predicate function?" - **it isn't** when you use the predicate function from my answer.